# Breakfast bar. How should it have been done?

Tags: kitchens, safety, kitchen-counters

We have just moved in a new apartment. It's a rental but it's a new luxury condominium and nobody lived in this place before us. Today I noticed something weird in our kitchen. The breakfast bar is not resting on the brackets and the top only seems to be attached to the side with some silicone seal. Obviously the brackets bit has to be fixed but before I kick a fuss about the attachment of the top to the leg/side, can someone confirm if this is safe or should there be some metal brackets there? The picture shows the bar seam from underneath. I hope you can ignore the kitchen reflecting from the leg/side. I have a very active kid and wouldn't want this to land on her.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the materials, the top may be jointed to the side internally and it may be perfectly safe. If I were designing a breakfast bar, I certainly wouldn't wish to see brackets underneath but I'd find another way to fix the top securely.

You may be right; safety first especially if children are around. Why not simply lift the top hard and see if it moves? If in doubt, call a professional out.